# можно ли сделать мультизагрузочную флешку, которую можно использовать как и обычную флешку

Tags: linux, usb, iso-образ, iso

не хочу лишаться флешки из-за нескольких образов. Программы на подобие rufus полностью стирают содержимое, когда делают флешку загрузочной. Возникают еще и такие вопросы:
можно ли копировать iso файлы на флешку без программы rufus как обычные файлы, но с возможностью установить ОС;
как сделать мультизагрузочную флешку и как записывать на нее образы

Comment: Набираете в chrome "мультизагрузочная флешка с несколькими ос" - тьма результатов
   https://habr.com/ru/post/575642/

Comment: Или купите винчестер и бокс к нему типа https://www.nix.ru/autocatalog/HDDBox_Zalman/Zalman-ZM-VE350-Black-Vneshnij-boks-dlya-25-SATA-HDD-USB30-Al-emulyator-CD-DVD-Blu-ray_208988.html чтобы можно было хранить и данные и выбирать на дисплее нужный iso для загрузки

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте Ventoy https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html Устанавливаете Ventoy на флешку. Она создает раздел как в обычной флешке. Пользуететсь им как обычно. Но если запишите него iso образы и загрузитесь с нее, то появится окно Ventoy с предложением загрузиться с любого образа, который находится на флешке.